# javascript window unload event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calculating how many users online, but if a person close a window without logging out, he is not online, I need to make that user logout dynamically through javascript or jquery.
when i use body `onunload` event to check this it works but if i refresh the page it also calls the body unload event.

Here is my code

```
<script>
function LogmeOut()
{
  window.location='logout.php';
}
</script
<body onUnload="LogmeOut();">
   .....
   .....
</body>
```

The logout php will signout the current user before closing the window.
Any suggestions?

Comment: you cannot do this complete with UI or jquery , you need backend support like session management.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a reliable way to tell.

Best thing to do is when the user accesses a page, update their *activity* in the database and set a new expiry (e.g. 15 minutes).

If the user has had no activity when you query, you could perhaps count them as offline.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the best way to manage sessions IMO, which is to work around the concept of timeouts. If the user hasn't been active for x amount of time, then they are logged out.

Answer (score 0):

I like Alex's answer, if you go about tracking your active users through JavaScript, it will definitely have errors due to crashing browsers, "active" but actually inactive users who left their browsers idle etc...

Alex's method avoids all that.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `window.onunload`, I would prefer using `window.onbeforeunload` and then make an ajax call to logout.php  like following:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    // make an ajax call to logout.php
};
```